# Ssecure communication between Docker container and an Elasticsearch server?

Tags: tls, http, docker

I have a spring boot application running inside a Docker container. This application communicates with another server which hosts Elasticsearch on it. How do I secure the communication between these two entities in my architecture?

Comment: TLS is the solution for your problem. Check if elasticsearch have support for TLS(probably does) and your application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up TLS support on the Elastic Search cluster, which is well documented by the vendor: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/ssl-tls.html

Then you need to re-configure all method(s) your application uses in your docker container to connect to the TLS secured end-points in your Elastic Search cluster. For instance replace `http://hostname.example.com:some-port/some-path` use `https://hostname.example.com:other-port/some-path`.